# Fill automatically Google Forms

Tags: python, google-forms

I have a Google Form that I would like to compile automatically. Can you please help me? This is my attempt:

The link to the form is [this](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe8Wj3QAV0LPYGPODkNCK_JSfoacBWUX_3Uq7gTlJB9icBgGQ/viewform). I was trying to use Selenium to interact with the page.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import random

# Khai báo danh sách các đáp án có thể chọn ngẫu nhiên
answers = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]

# Khai báo đường dẫn của biểu mẫu Google Form
url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe8Wj3QAV0LPYGPODkNCK_JSfoacBWUX_3Uq7gTlJB9icBgGQ/viewform"

# Khai báo số lượng email cần tạo và điền vào biểu mẫu
num_emails = 100
for i in range(num_emails):
    # Tạo một email giả mạo bằng cách sử dụng các thư viện Python phù hợp
    email = "test{}@example.com".format(i)
    
    # Khởi tạo trình duyệt và mở đường dẫn của biểu mẫu
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    
    email_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='entry.1170127610']") # Thay thế "entry.987654321" bằng id của ô email trong biểu mẫu của bạn
    email_field.send_keys(email)
    
    # Chọn một câu trả lời ngẫu nhiên từ danh sách các đáp án
    answer_choice = random.choice(answers)
    answer = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-value='{}']".format(answer_choice))
    answer.click()
    
    # Gửi biểu mẫu và đóng trình duyệt
    submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Submit']")
    submit.click()
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: what's the issue that you're having?

Comment: it

Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'
  File "C:\Users\thanh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\webdriver.py", line 21, in <module>
    email_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='entry.1170127610']") # Thay thế "entry.987654321" bằng id của ô email trong biểu mẫu của bạn
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'